# Browserify not working properly in Gulp

Tags: javascript, build, gulp, browserify, concatenation

I don't know if I missed something or made a mistake. But requiring a module only returns an empty object.

This is just a sample of my project.

Tools I'm using:

```
gulp - 3.9.1
browserify - 13.0.0
vinyl-source-stream - 1.1.0
```

Here is my working directory:

```
root/
  dist/
  src/
    external.js
    main.js
gulpfile.js
```

main.js

```
var External = require('./external.js');
console.log(External);
```

external.js

```
function Hello() {
  return 'Hello from the otherside!';
}

module.exports = {
  testFunc: Hello
};
```

gulpfile.js

```
var browserify = require('browserify');
var vinyl_source_stream = require('vinyl-source-stream');

gulp.task('concat', function() {
  return browserify('./src/main.js')
    .bundle()
    .pipe(vinyl_source_stream('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))
});
```

Comment: you need to require browserify and vinyl in your gulpfile.js. and be sure your external.js' path is correct, since we don't know the error happens on which file.

Comment: yes I did require them, and also there are no errors in the terminal

Comment: stupid mistake. in my project, I didn't notice that the `module.exports` was inside the function that's why the require statement returns an empty object

Answer (score 0):

**First**:

```
module.exports = function() { 
  testFunc: Hello
};
```

so that you can export an object prototype.

**Second**

```
var External = require('./external.js')(); // Notice the ()
```

so that you can execute that prototype and get an instance of the object.